# removeLetters from a string

Tags: java, string, replace, removeall, letter

Here I am trying to remove specified letters from a string text and return the new text.

```java
static String removeLetters(String text, String letters){   
    for(int k=0; k<=letters.length()-1; k++){
        char c=letters.charAt(k);
        for(int j=0; j<=text.length()-1; j++){
            if(text.charAt(j)==letters.charAt(k)){
                text=text.replaceAll(letters.charAt(k), "");
            }
        }   
    }
  //return buf.toString();
    return text;
}   

public static void main (String [] args){
    String text="Dieser Text ist moeglicherweise auch ohne Vokale lesbar!";
    String letters="aeiou";
    Out.println(removeLetters(text,letters));
}
```

The function `removeLetters` should remove all [a, e, i, o, u] letters. But I am not allowed to use the following method: `text=text.replaceAll("[a,e,i,o,u]", "");`

Answer (score 1):

Here's 3 potential options you can try.

1. Remove the letters manually by traversing through your `String` and
   see if a letter is supposed to be removed.
2. Since you can't use `replaceAll()` just use `replace()` and replace each letter to remove with an empty `String`
3. You can split the string apart by the letters you want to remove and then join the pieces back together.

**CODE**

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Question {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        String text="Dieser Text ist moeglicherweise auch ohne Vokale lesbar!";
        String letters="aeiou";
        System.out.println(removeLettersManually(text,letters));
        System.out.println(removeLettersWithReplace(text,letters));
        System.out.println(removeLettersWithSplit(text,letters));
    }

    static String removeLettersManually(String text, String lettersToRemove){   
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            if (!lettersToRemove.contains(text.charAt(i) + "")) {
                sb.append(text.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }   

    static String removeLettersWithReplace(String text, String lettersToRemove) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lettersToRemove.length(); i++) {
            text = text.replace(lettersToRemove.charAt(i) + "", "");
        }

        return text;
    }

    static String removeLettersWithSplit(String text, String lettersToRemove) {
        // Wrap letters to remove in [] to make a regex pattern of [aeiou], this way the split will function on each individual letter
        String[] pieces = text.split("[" + lettersToRemove + "]");
        return String.join("", pieces);
    }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
Dsr Txt st mglchrws ch hn Vkl lsbr!
Dsr Txt st mglchrws ch hn Vkl lsbr!
Dsr Txt st mglchrws ch hn Vkl lsbr!
```

Comment: I tried your second solution "removeLettersWithReplace" and it worked! Thank you really much for your effort :)

Comment: @huettl You’re welcome. Check the check mark if this has answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my interpretaiton of what you are trying to do. I have created an array of all illegal characters and using a nested for loop I iterate over every element checking to see if it is contained inside my array, if i see an illegal character inside my string I set a flag to true and ignore it, if character isn't inside my array and my flag is false I append this to a new String.

```
static char[] removeChar = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Dieser Text ist moeglicherweise auch ohne Vokale lesbar!";
        System.out.println(removeLetters(text));


    }

    static String removeLetters(String text) {

        StringBuilder afterRemoval = new StringBuilder(); //Create a new variable to hold our string once all illegal chars have been removed.

        for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            char tempChar = text.charAt(i); //Obtain char from text at index i -> text at index i on first iteration = 'D'
            boolean inString = false; //If an illegal char is found set flag to true so that we don't append to our new string.

            for (char c : removeChar) { //Check if our temp variable is equal to any element of our removeChar array, if so set flag to true and break.
                if (tempChar == c) {
                    inString = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!inString) //If flag is still false, append tempChar to our new String.
                afterRemoval.append(tempChar);

        }

        return afterRemoval.toString(); //Return string after all illegal chars have been removed.

    }
```